# Spring cache keys for Collections

Tags: ehcache, spring-cache

In spring cache(ehcache), we can give a key for single parameter or result.
As an example:

```
@CachePut(value="employeeCache", key="#employeeId")
public void addEmployee( int employeeId ){ //body }

@Cacheable(value="employeeCache", key="#result.id")
public Employee getEmployee( int employeeId ){ return employeeObj; }
```

But How can we define keys for collections like Set, List using annotations?

Comment: Are you talking about a `@Cacheable` method that would take a list of parameters?  The key this same list? Or a `@CachePut` for which you want to cache many results (from the list returned)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to know both of them.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the parameters are used for the key. So if you pass a collection in parameter, the collection will be the key. Then it all depends on the cache implementation. In general, it will behave like a map so the `equals` and `hashcode` of the collection will be used to find the cache entry. That's how Ehcache works.

If you want to cache each entry of a collection returned by a `CachePut` method per id... then I don't think it is possible. You will need to do it manually. However, of course, the entire collection can be cached with the defined key.